# select default value when record not found in where

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, 0), COALESCE(B, 0)
FROM TABLE
WHERE Id IN (0, 2, 0);
```

How would it be possible to return a default value when no record is found based on the where clause? The following is the expected result:

```
0, 0
1, 1
0, 0
```

Note that when the Id is zero, a value must still be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select from a [VALUES derived table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) and join on your table:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, 0), COALESCE(B, 0)
FROM (VALUES (0),(2),(0)) x(Id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TABLE] ON [TABLE].Id = x.Id
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/179ee/1)

---

If the returned order must be maintained, you can explicitly specify it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, 0), COALESCE(B, 0)
FROM (VALUES (0,0),(1,2),(2,0)) x(SeqNo, Id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TABLE] ON [TABLE].Id = x.Id
ORDER BY SeqNo
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/179ee/2) (no real visible changes, but the ordering is now guaranteed)